# External and internal CSS styles at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I working with images at this moment, in my html document. A don't want, that adjust image width for each `img` element, so I made separated class (for e. `thumbnail`) for `img` tag in my `style.css`, but that doesn't works. Then I'd created `style` in my `head` tag, and placed the `thumbnail` class in there. That works, but now my `style.css` doesn't works at all. What I should do?
**EDIT:**
Working example:
`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="@">
                    <img src="plug.png" class="thumbnail">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`style.css`:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.thumbnail{
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

link should have a href instead of src

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

Comment: That works, thank you! Now, I don't need to use `style` tag.